# I'm having difficulty converting this sql query to laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, database, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to convert this SQL query to Eloquent in Laravel.

My DB is PostgreSQL

```
SELECT
    mc.*,
    COUNT(co.*) as total_calls,
    sum(CASE WHEN co.client_type_oid = 1 THEN 1 else 0 END ) as total_potential
FROM
    campaigns as mc left outer join contacts as co
    on (co.created_at BETWEEN mc.start_date AND mc.end_date + INTERVAL '2 day')
Group By mc.id
ORDER BY mc.id DESC;
```

what I need is to get all records from campaigns table with the count of all records from contacts table that created between start and end date of each campaign `AS total_calls`

and `sum(CASE WHEN co.client_type_oid = 1 THEN 1 else 0 END ) as total_potential`

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Do you want convert results to eloquent model only or also query?

Comment: Have you created models and relationships between them? Please help to add more details to your question.

Comment: @prashant-pokhriyal yes i have models by actually there is no need for a relationship
i need to get all recordes from campaigns table with the count of all records from contacts table that created between start and end date of each campaign

Comment: @nuriddin-rashidov I want it in any laravel query, but it would be better if it was eloquent